# Adding LOOP to my Stored PROCEDURE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below is a sample of my stored procedure, can someone help me how I have the following error:

```
'Msg 22027, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Usage:  EXECUTE xp_fileexist <filename> [, <file_exists INT> OUTPUT]
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TextImpoted01, Line 39
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'No' to data type int.'
```

---

```
USE [test]

GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO    
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TextImpoted01]    
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(100) 

SELECT TOP (1) @SQL = total  FROM DealCounter


DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(max)    
SET @path = 'c:\temp\TextImpoted'+ @SQL + '.txt'    


DECLARE @UpdateSQL NVARCHAR(100)     
SET @UpdateSQL = N'UPDATE    DealCounter  SET total = total  + 1' 


DECLARE @LOOP NVARCHAR(100)     
SELECT TOP (1) @LOOP = total  FROM DealCounter

DECLARE @bulk_cmd NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @isExists INT


WHILE @SQL <= @LOOP + 1000
BEGIN

    SET @path = 'c:\temp\TextImpoted'+ @SQL + '.txt'    
    exec master.dbo.xp_fileexist @path ,isExists out


    SELECT  case @isExists 
                when 1 then 'Yes'     
                else 'No'    
            end as isExists


    if @isExists = 'No'    
        BREAK

    else
        SET @bulk_cmd = 'BULK INSERT TextImpoted FROM '''+ @path + ''' 
                WITH 
                (
                FIELDTERMINATOR = ' + ''';''' +  ',       ROWTERMINATOR = ' + '''\n'''+ ')';

    EXEC sp_executesql @bulk_cmd

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @UpdateSQL;

    set @SQL = @SQL + 1;


END
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem actually doesn't concerns loops.

You are declaring `@isExists` as `integer` here:

```
DECLARE @isExists INT
```

And here you're comparing it with `varchar` value.

```
if @isExists = 'No'
```

This produces error you've seen.

Also note this line of code:

```
exec master.dbo.xp_fileexist @path ,isExists out
```

It is definitely should be `@isExists` here and you're missing `@`

Answer (score 1):

First: The output variable from `exec master.dbo.xp_fileexist @path ,isExists out`
 lacks an `@` sign and should be `exec master.dbo.xp_fileexist @path , @isExists out`.

Second: The error comes from trying to compare the INT variable @isExists with a char value in the case statement.

The `case` block is redundant however and could be replaced with:

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @path ,@isExists OUT
IF (@isExists = 1)
    BEGIN
       (... your logic here ... )
    END
```